# Rails 3.1 asset pipeline not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, asset-pipeline

I am in the process of upgrading an old app to the asset pipline but after following the ryan bates tutorial on upgrading to 3.1 I am still not able to take advantage of the pipline. In order to rule out my upgrade process I created a fresh rails app and attempted some coffee scripting and adding other files to the /assets/javascripts folder, however any additional files besides the application.js do not seem to be rendered.

This is my application.js file:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into including all the files listed below.
// Add new JavaScript/Coffee code in separate files in this directory and they'll automatically
// be included in the compiled file accessible from http://example.com/assets/application.js
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .


alert("this displays fine");
```

And the additional dogs.js.coffee file:

```
# Place all the behaviors and hooks related to the matching controller here.
# All this logic will automatically be available in application.js.
# You can use CoffeeScript in this file: http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/

alert "cant see this!"
```

It seems to be a sprockets issue but I really cant find anyone with the same problem, or info on when additional javascript files within the assets folder are not included in the application.js via the require_tree .

Here is my gem file:

```
gem 'rails', '3.1.1'
gem 'sqlite3'
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.1.4'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
gem 'jquery-rails'

group :test do
  # Pretty printed test output
  gem 'turn', :require => false
end
```

my ruby version is 2.0.0p195

thanks for any help!

G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the ruby version was my problem, I downgraded to ruby 1.9.3, then reinstalled gems and it works now!